My binary is not establishing SCTP connection when running using Valgrind
In my program two binaries are there, one binary [let's call it binary1] is trying to establish SCTP connection with the other binary[let's call it binary2].
In normal condition binary1 is able to form the connection with  binary2 without any problem and the program is working as expected.
I wanted to check binary2's memory leaks using Valgrind.
I am running
valgrind -s --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --main-stacksize=4194304 ./binary2

and
./binary1

But now I am getting from binary1.
sctp_connectx:: Connection refused
sctp_connectx:: Connection refused
sctp_connectx:: Connection refused
sctp_connectx:: Connection refused
sctp_connectx:: Connection refused
sctp_connectx:: Connection refused
sctp_connectx:: Connection refused
sctp_connectx:: Connection refused
sctp_connectx:: Connection refused

I checked with # ps -T -p 14805 - where 14805 is pid of binary2
   PID    SPID TTY          TIME CMD
  14805   14805 ttyS0    00:15:19 memcheck-arm64-
  14805   19129 ttyS0    00:00:00 LOG_READER
  14805   19207 ttyS0    00:00:00 eal-intr-thread
  14805   19208 ttyS0    00:00:00 rte_mp_handle

The rest of the threads are not spawned because I suspect they cannot bind to port due to some configuration problem in Valgrind.
Can anyone tell me what should I do?

I would recommend to use address sanitizer instead valgrind. Disadvantage you have to rebuild your program. Advantages: program will work faster (comparing to when run with valgrind), it is able to detect more issues, has less false positives.

BTW performance penalty when using valgrind is quite big. Did you wait long enough so process of binary2 is in a state where it can accept connections? One of the reasons Connection refused can appear is when server is not ready yet.

You can check list of open ports by doing: lsof -Pan -p <PID> -i

what I know is that Valgrind doesn't affect the SCTP connection at all, we use it everywhere and we have never faced something like this, I feel that (Marek R) comment about waiting binary2 long enough is something to consider.

Hard to tell without seeing the code for client and server. Most likely connection timeout occurs due to valgrind significantly slowing down one of the binaries. Or maybe some bug that didn't manifest itself without valrgind. In any case, your application should be robust enough to work with limited resources and under different conditions.

hey @MarekR had waited for 4-5 hours, still not working

What OS? Which version of Valgrind? Why the big stack? Can you try running with ‘—tool=none’ and no other options?

@MarekR I'm not aware of any memcheck false positives, do you have some examples?

@PaulFloyd I didn't use valgrind for very log time, but here is SO question about false positives (personally I've seen example of that, but do not remember details).  And here is my question about address sanitizer false positive.

@MarekR perhaps you should refrain from commenting on things that  you know little about. I don’t count digging up 15 year old SO posts.
